# optimal ubuntu home server/raid setup

Tags: server, hardware, raid

I have two machines at home (plus laptop and work laptop) that I just put in rackmount cases. Right now each machine has several drives not set up with RAID.

In the not too distant future, I want to use the machine that is my main win/ubuntu desktop for a server. The case has lots of room for 10/15 drives or so, so I want to make a good size raid partition.

I use the server for a web server, mysql host, mercurial code repo host, samba share file storage.

I want to centralize all my file storage, especially music and photos which are currently on my desktop and will take up a lot of space.

Is it common to build one big raid partition and put everything I want on it? Or should mysql, and the web server be in their own area?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first big hurdle you will face is having enough drive interface ports for that number of drives, and then ensuring that the case has enough power and cooling capacity for that many drives as well. If those can be addressed, then the question becomes what type of RAID are you going to run, or use multiple RAIDs?

Support for hardware RAIDs is fairly good, though not all RAID cards are fully supported or without issues. Ubuntu/Linux is flexible enough to handle multiple software RAID setups in one box.

Ultimately, you need to match up your needs of speed/redundancy and your mix of drives to determine what RAID configs are going provide for each purpose.